# Disabling focus() from being run in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, focus

I've got a page that has an iframe and web page in the iframe runs a focus() on one an input box in the iframe... how can I prevent that focus() from running?

Comment: Is the iframe hosted on your domain? I'm not entirely sure you can do much about it.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you're able to do this, unless there's some sort of weird browser quirk in that if you set focus on your outer page it gains priority over the iframe.

Comment: +1: I would try to set focus on the parent page and see if that overrides the focus from the iframe

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are allowed to access input boxes in an iframe if the page is from a remote source due to cross-domain security limitations.